# GdkPixbuf can be created with `new_from_data` and `new_from_stream`. Why doesn't the latter require the resolution?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, gdkpixbuf, pixbuf

I am trying to understand the basics behind `Pixbuf` and its factory methods `new_from_data` and `new_from_stream`.

`new_from_data` requires a string of bytes containing the image data, and other information such as bits per sample, with and height of image.

What I don't understand is why `new_from_stream` does not require those additional image information. Then, how can the Pixbuf know how to render the image `new_from_stream` does not provide any additional information other than the `Gio.InputStream` ?

Answer (score 1):

`new_from_stream()` expects to get a stream of a supported image file, equivalent to `new_from_file()`. All the image formats contain metadata like height and width.

`new_from_data()` on the other hand expects a pixel buffer, which is essentially just an array of pixels without any metadata.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering: would it be possible (and efficient) to keep a pixbuf and changing the data ( data similar to the one provided by `new_from_data`)? This because I fear that `new_from_stream` is less fast as it needs to parse an image format, hence might not be suitable for displaying videos generated on-the-fly.

Comment: If you need to somehow touch the picture often (like every draw cycle) then modifying  the data definitely sounds a _lot_ better than creating a new pixbuf everytime: memory allocation takes a while... Maybe  `get_pixels()` is useful for you.

Comment: isn't a "bytes" object (the one returned by `get_pixels()` ) immutable in python?